# 和がkとなるようなn個の非負整数の順列を全列挙する

Tags: アルゴリズム

和がkとなるようなn個の非負整数の順列を重複なく全列挙する方法が知りたいです．

ナイーブに実装しましたが`O(k^n)`，これより計算量が改善される解法は存在しますか．

```py
# Python 3.10.5

from itertools import product

def sol(n, k):
    for perm in product(range(k+1), repeat=n):
        if sum(perm) == k:
            yield perm

print(*sol(n=2, k=4))
# (0, 4) (1, 3) (2, 2) (3, 1) (4, 0)
print(*sol(n=3, k=3))
# (0, 0, 3) (0, 1, 2) (0, 2, 1) (0, 3, 0) (1, 0, 2) (1, 1, 1) (1, 2, 0) (2, 0, 1) (2, 1, 0) (3, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

数値の分割位置の組み合わせで考えればよさそうです。

k個の「〇」が並べてあって、「〇」の間に間仕切り「|」を(n-1)個入れて分割することを考えます。
例えば、k=n=3の場合は、以下のようになります。

||〇〇〇 = (0,0,3)
|〇|〇〇 = (0,1,2)
...
〇〇〇|| = (3,0,0)

さて、間仕切りを配置できる箇所は、「〇」の間と前後で(k+1)箇所あります。
間仕切りは、同じ場所に複数配置できるので、重複組み合わせを使えばパターンを網羅できます。
重複組み合わせは、Pythonだと`itertools`の`combinations_with_replacement`で生成できます。
あとは、間仕切りの配置場所から、数値の組み合わせへの変換を行えば、目的の順列の全列挙ができます。

```python
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, pairwise

def sol(n, k):
    for c in combinations_with_replacement(range(k + 1), n - 1):
        yield tuple(b - a for a, b in pairwise((0, *c, k)))
```

Answer (score 0):

若干計算量が改善された解法を共有します．

```py
# Python 3.10.5

from itertools import product

def sol(n, k):
    for perm in product(range(k+1), repeat=n-1):
        if (x := sum(perm)) <= k:
            yield *perm, k-x
```